# Baking a byte array into dynamic IL

Tags: c#, reflection, cil, reflection.emit

I am writing a performance-oriented data deserializer by emitting IL. The serialized data is `UTF8`, and the fields are denoted as strings.

```
[FieldA]: 22
[FieldB]: 16
```

I have already written a custom reader that properly tokenizes the serialized data and provides a `ReadOnlySpan<byte>` as it steps through the serialized data.

I would like to have a static, inline deserializer that is able to have the byte signatures of the fields packed in so that I can easily create a jump table and set the appropriate fields.

How non-dynamic code might look:

```
// byteSpan is a ReadOnlySpan<byte> containing the signature

var signatureA = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( "FieldA" );
var signatureB = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( "FieldB" );
if( byteSpan.SequenceEqual( signatureA ) )
  DoSomething();
else if ( byteSpan.SequenceEqual( signatureB ) )
  DoSomething();
...
```

How the jump table is being emitted:

```
var fieldSignatures = GetTypeSignatures<T>(); // Returns a Tuple<byte[], FieldInfo>
var setFieldLabels = new List<Tuple<FieldInfo, Label>>();

foreach( (byte[] signature, FieldInfo field) in fieldSignatures )
{
  var setFieldLabel = il.DefineLabel();
  setFieldLabels.Add( Tuple.Create( field, setFieldLabel ) );

  il.Emit( OpCodes.Ldloc_1 ); // Load the current ReadOnlySpan<byte>
  // Inline load byte[] signature here
  il.Emit( OpCodes.Call, METHOD_SEQUENCEEQUAL );
  il.Emit( OpCodes.Brtrue, setFieldLabel );
}

EmitFieldSetters( setFieldLabels, ref il );
```

Is there a way I can bake the signature byte arrays directly into the IL that I am emitting so that they are a part of the delegate?

These signatures are generated at runtime based on type information, so manually defining them in a static class isn't feasible. A workaround could be to define a new dynamic `Assembly` and `Type` and store the bytes in there, but I would like to avoid having to do that if possible.

Comment: Since you're using trying to increase performance by emitting IL, is performing what amounts to a linear search on the field signatures really the best way to do this? It would seem a more optimal lookup mechanism (even implemented *without* emitting IL) might out-perform a linear lookup even with custom IL.

Comment: This doesn't look good.  At least look at the code that the C# compiler generates when you use switch(stringvar), it is much, much more efficient than what you're doing now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you might want to do is pass an array of signature byte arrays (`byte[][]`) as a hidden first argument to the dynamic method.

You could load the appropriate byte array via something like:

```
// Load the first byte[][] signatures array argument
il.Emit( OpCodes.LdArg_0 );
// Load the index into the signatures array
il.Emit( OpCodes.Ldc_I4, signatureIndex );
// Fetch the signature byte[] element from the array
il.Emit( OpCodes.Ldelem_Ref );
```

Then when you create the delegate from the dynamic method, you can use the overload that takes a target object, which becomes the (hidden) first argument:

```
var deserializerDelegate = dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(YourDelegateType), signatures);
```

This all being said, see my comment on your question above regarding looking at using an alternative signature lookup algorithm which may be more optimal than a linear search, even with dynamically generated IL.

Comment: I'm not familiar any alternate search algorithms... The object fields are always going to be identified by their string name (which is what the signature is derived from). Do you have an algorithm in mind that would apply to this?

Comment: @Haus - just using the built-in `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` to look up setter delegates based on the field name would likely be far more efficient than the linear search you're implementing in custom IL.